# Add custom resolution to built-in laptop screen in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display, resolution

My laptop is a Lenovo W530. I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and after some problems, I managed to get it working at 1920 x 1080. However, this resolution is a bit too high for me, so I would like to add another one, but there is no other option in System Settings > Screen Display.

I have tried following the instructions on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions) (Adding undetected resolutions section), but I am too much of a beginner to know what I am doing. I believe all the solutions that I have tried are for external monitors, but I would like to change my laptop's screen resolution.

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, could anyone throw a suggestion?

**EDIT**

I have managed to get a list of resolution by following the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269901/ubuntu-12-10-cant-add-custom-resolution). However, changing the resolution makes the screen be replicated 4 times and it unusable. What should I do now?